# rewrite url for videos with dynamic links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a video sharing website where users upload their videos and get a link for the video, here is an example of the video link:

```
 http://example.com/user/files/index.php?id=123&name=abc
```

the Url I want is

```
http://example.com/user/f/123/abc
```

Id parameter is the identifier (id) of the video and the name is optional.If a user forgot to write the *name* parameter ,then the URL will be like this

```
   http://example.com/user/f/123
```

but it should still reach the destination . What should I put in my htaccess to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `Root/.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
 #if the Requested filename is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #if the Requested filename is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #if above conditions are true then rewrite the url
RewriteRule ^user/f/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$ /user/files/index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Second capture group in the `RewriteRule` is optional here so that your video URL can accept both, `/123/` or `/123/abc` .

Comment: Thanks it works but now I have a problem ,css stylesheet is not working, how to solve this?